# Booting a raw file of cloned aws instance on KVM

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services

I am trying to boot a cloned image on KVM ,which is in the raw format, the image is a clone of aws ubuntu 14.04 LTS hvm instance. It gives me an error saying no bootable device found. The same image boots up when I specify the kernel path explicitly while creating the VM.
I am using virt-manager to create the VM and the qemu version is 2.0.0
I have tried changing the disk bus but nothing helped.
Can anyone help ?

Comment: That often means the image you're trying to boot does not have a bootloader installed.  You can correct that by booting it with an explicit kernel, making sure than an appropriate kernel is installed on the disk itself, and then installing a bootloader such as grub2 or syslinux.

Comment: The image which I'm trying to boot already has grub2 in it but it is not being detected when I create the VM using virt-manager on KVM.

Comment: It was because of the partitions on the Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Cloned the entire disk. Boots up fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because of the partitions on the Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Cloned the entire disk. Boots up fine now.